# ffmpeg - converting one audio track of a multi-track mp4

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, aac

I'm having a few mp4 with two audio tracks,
an english one in aac and a french one in dts.

Now I want to **convert *only* the french dts to eac3** with a single ffmpeg command.

I use

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.mp4 ^
             -map_metadata -1 ^
             -map 0:0 -c:v copy ^
             -map 0:1 -c:a copy ^
             -map 0:2 -c:a eac3 -b:a 1536k ^
             -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng ^
             -metadata:s:a:0 title="Stereo" ^
             -metadata:s:a:1 language=fra ^
             -metadata:s:a:1 title="Stereo" ^
output.mp4
```

This works quite nice, **but it converts both audio tracks** to eac3, instead of leaving the first one untouched ...
What's wrong in the command?

(ffmpeg version 2023-12-23-git-f5f414d9c4-full_build-www.gyan.dev under Windows 10)

Comment: Replace `-c:a eac3` by `-c:a:1 eac3` to convert only second audio track

Comment: In the mapping part shouldn't it be -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 instead of -map 0:1 -map 0:2....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research (Alain got me on the right way), the correct command is

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.mp4 ^
         -map_metadata -1 ^
         -map 0:0 -c:v copy ^
         -map 0:1 -c:a:0 copy ^
         -map 0:2 -c:a:1 eac3 -b:a:1 1536k ^
         -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng ^
         -metadata:s:a:0 title="Stereo" ^
         -metadata:s:a:1 language=fra ^
         -metadata:s:a:1 title="Stereo" ^
output.mp4
```

Both **-c:a:1 eac3** and **-b:a:1 1536k** are needed, if you only use -b:a instead of -b:a:1, all audio tracks are put to 1536k regardless of the codec...

The **-map** and **-metadata** statements are only needed if you remap the tracks and/or set the metadata.